# How should I unit test methods with lots of DOC's (depended-on code)?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

Let's say we have a method that mostly wires together various other methods; doesn't do a whole lot of its own logic.  Let's say it's a typical member of a service class in a Service Layer, calling methods in domain model (business) classes, data access classes, and an email utility / service class.

I'm finding that writing a true unit test for this method requires lots of test double setup, and there's very little logic being tested here.  It *seems* like the cost is going to outweigh the value if I continue this way.  What should I do?

Comment: An example of the unit test would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a purist when it comes to unit tests.  There is a point of diminishing returns, where the cost to create and maintain a given test is conceivably greater than the benefit you will receive from executing that test.  However there is no hard and fast rule as to where that point exists.

I have opted to write unit tests for code similar to what you described.  However in most of those cases I made sure that the underlying objects (which you would be mocking) have appropriate unit tests running against them.  However in cases where there is a significant amount of internal logic, unit testing is still definitely the order of the day.

I don't think there is a right answer to this question, but hopefully my comments below help your thought process on how and whether you should unit test this.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have more than one mock per unit test. From *The Art of Unit Testing* by Roy Osherove (p. 94):

> In a test where you test only one
>   thing (which is how I recommend you
>   write tests), there should be no more
>   than one mock object. All other fake
>   objects will act as stubs. Having more
>   than one mock per test usually means
>   you’re testing more than one thing,
>   and this can lead to complicated or
>   brittle tests.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405518/how-can-i-deal-with-too-many-mock-expectations-in-unit-tests) is a related stack overflow question that may be of help.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the term "mock" in the general sense--i.e., Test Double (using xUnit Test Patterns lingo).  I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: but you still make a good point that I never thought of, so +1.